# Cytoscape.js "Maximum callstack size exceeded" Error after migrating to Angular 12

Tags: angular, stack-overflow, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, zone

Recently, I've migrated an Angular application from version 10 to 12. Since I migrated, a component, which uses cytoscape.js to visualize a graph, produces the following error:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
```

This error happens when i initialize Cytoscape by calling its constructor like this:

```
 this.cytoscape = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cytoscape-canvas-area'), //This line causes the error
  elements: {...initialGraph} as any,
  style: GRAPH_STYLES,
  layout: GRAPH_LAYOUT,
  autoungrabify: true,
  boxSelectionEnabled: true,
  panningEnabled: true,
  userPanningEnabled: true,
  userZoomingEnabled: true,
  zoomingEnabled: true,
  zoom: 1,
  minZoom: 0.1,
  maxZoom: 10,
});
```

While troubleshooting I found out, that the error happens as long as I have the line marked in the example above in my code. I already checked if `document.getElementById('cytoscape-canvas-area')` returns something, which is the case.

Heres my package.json with all the versions:

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/elements": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/localize": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.9.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
"@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
"@types/cytoscape": "^3.14.17",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
"angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"concurrently": "^5.1.0",
"cytoscape": "^3.19.1",
"cytoscape-canvas": "^3.0.1",
"cytoscape-cxtmenu": "^3.1.2",
"cytoscape-dagre": "^2.3.2",
"document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
"http-server": "^0.12.1",
"jest": "^27.0.6",
"jest-preset-angular": "^9.0.5",
"live-server": "^1.2.1",
"moment": "^2.26.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
"ngx-build-plus": "^10.1.1",
"rxjs": "^6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4" },

 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~12.2.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"cytoscape-edgehandles": "^3.6.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.5"
},
```

I'd be really glad if someone could help me :)

### Update 1

When I setup a new Angular 12 Application and add Cytoscape.js, everything works fine. The error only appears only in this project. I migrated using ng update and following the official update guide from Angular. Unfortunately I can't just use a new projcet because this project is in productive use.

### Update 2

`this.cytoscape = cytoscape(...)` is called in the `ngOnChanges` loop after I've fetched some data from a remote server. I already checked the structure of the passed data and it is correct.

```
this.graphService.getByUuidWithNodesAndEdges(uuid).subscribe(graphData => {
  this.cytoscapeService.createCanvas(graphData);
});
```

`cytoscapeService`is a service created by myself which manages all code related to the framework.

```
createCanvas(initialGraph: GraphCyo) {
   this.cytoscape = cytoscape({
     container: document.getElementById('cytoscape-canvas-area'),
     elements: {...initialGraph} as any,
     ...otherConfig
   });
}
```

### Update 3

The error has nothing to do with the wrong Angular Lifecycle Hook or loading to much data. The same exception also appears when I add a button to my View which triggers the initialization of cytoscape with some dummy data:

```
<div style="background: #ffcc00; height: 500px; width: 500px" id="test-container-cy-bug">
```

```
<button style="position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 99" (click)="initCytoscapeCanvas()">Init!</button>
```

And then the init Method:

```
initCytoscapeCanvas() {
   this.cytoscape = cytoscape({
     container: document.getElementById('test-container-cy-bug'),
     elements: [
       {
         group: 'nodes',
         data: {
           id: '1'
         }
       },
       {
         group: 'nodes',
         data: {
           id: '2'
         }
       },
       {
         group: 'edges',
         data: {
           id: 'e',
           source: '1',
           target: '2'
         }
       }
     ]
   });
 }
```

The error appears when I click on the `Init!` button:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
    at V.y.<computed>.get (polyfills.js:1)
defaultErrorLogger  @   core.js:6479
handleError @   core.js:6527
handleError @   core.js:10938
executeListenerWithErrorHandling    @   core.js:15311
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault   @   core.js:15346
(anonymous) @   platform-browser.js:561
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:421
onInvokeTask    @   core.js:28659
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:420
Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:503
invokeTask  @   zone.js:1671
globalZoneAwareCallback @   zone.js:1697
```

Comment: `Maximum callstack size exceeded` Error occurs when a function is repeatedly called,

Comment: did you used `ng update` command? It should be fine. Try putting cytoscape.js into a brand new angular 12 project

Comment: @canbax Yup, used ```ng update``` to migrate. Tried to put cytoscape in a new NG-12 project and everything went fine. So for me it's pretty strange that it doesn't work in my current project.

Comment: Is `'cytoscape-canvas-area'` an empty `div`? Where are you calling `this.cytoscape = cytoscape(...)`?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Yes, ```cytoscape-canvas-area``` is an empty ```div```, positioned absolutely and ```height``` & ```width``` set manually.
```this.cytoscape = cytoscape(...)``` is called in the ```ngOnChanges``` loop after fetching some data (see **Update 2**)

Comment: @YouriWeber calling `this.cytoscape = cytoscape(...)` on `ngOnChanges` does not make sense. `cytoscape(...)` should only be called once  at the beginning or something like that. Calling `cytoscape(...)`  might fire `ngOnChanges` and then it might be causing a vicious cycle.

Comment: @canbax Yeah I agree, but the current project forces me to use ```ngOnChanges```. Yet, the error has nothing to do with the Lifecycle Hooks. It also appears when I add a button to my site, which start the initialization process when I click it. - See **Update 3**

Comment: you might try `ngZone.runOutsideAngular` method. Cytoscape.js causes unnecessary angular changes. The changes are inside a cytoscape.js canvas but they trigger angular to rerender the whole page.